# Replace multiple words in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub xLator2()
Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
Dim N As Long, i As Long
Dim from(), too()
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1") '   contains the data
Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2") '   contains the translation table

s2.Activate

N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim from(1 To N)
ReDim too(1 To N)
For i = 1 To N
    from(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    too(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i

s1.Activate

' -------------- Modification starts here --------------------------
' Replace from from(i) to __MYREPLACEMENTi__  (where i is the counter)
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__"
Next i
' Replace from __MYREPLACEMENTi__ to too(i)  (where i is the counter)
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__", Replacement:=too(i)
Next i
' -------------- Modification ends here --------------------------
End Sub
```

I am using above code to find and replace multiple words (in "Column A Sheet1" with words in "Column B Sheet 2") in below mentioned sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14ba9pQDjMPWJd4YFpGffhtVcHxml0LdUUVQ0prrOEUY/edit?usp=sharing

However when I apply this in another sheet (as mentioned below) for another data then code fails i.e. I get distorted words in sheet1:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1spvZAzxT1kB1bytCQaNQH7tl1DJSpLITYgW6P5dxbQE/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me out so that I can replace words in "Column A Sheet1" with words in "Column B Sheet2"

Note: Above links have been given of google spreadsheet however I am having problem in Excel 2007 sheet.

I request you to help me by giving whole revised code as I am not good in VBA

Comment: rather than relying on activating a sheet and using unqualified range references, fully qualify your range references.  That will give you more control over what is happening (or at least where it's happening).

Comment: How to qualify it? can you give me full code please, I know nothing about VBA, indeed I have got this code from somewhere else.

Comment: I could show you, but you'd learn a lot more if you researched it and tried to sort it out yourself (try googling fully qualify VBA range references).  If someone just gives you the answer, you're going to be right back here asking because you don't fully get what the code does.

Comment: I will definitely try in future but this time I require it urgent, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with sous2817: the more you solve your own problems, the faster you will develop.  However, I think a little advice will help.

You must learn VBA if you are going to use it. Finding, and attempting to use, a piece of code which you do not understand is never going to end well. This is particularly true when the author of this code only knows a little more than you.

Search the web for "Excel VBA Tutorial". There are many to choose from so try a few and complete one that matches your learning style. I prefer books. I visited a large library, reviewed their Excel VBA Primers and borrowed those I liked. After trying them out at home, I bought the one that suited me best.

Where did you get this code? It contains typical beginner mistakes and it does not work even with the first example.

The first word in Sheet1 is "it". Sheet2 indicates "it" is to be replaced by "that". The code correctly replaces "it" by "that" Unfortunately, it replaces all "it"s by "that"s so "with" is translated to "wthath" not "having".  Since you complain about the second pair of sheets, I assume you did not notice that mistranslation. Such mistranslations will be must more obvious in the second pair with the first word "the" appearing in "they", "there", "their", "them", "then" and "these".

If you look up the `Replace Method`, you should see a quick correction to this error.  Note: `Replace Method` not `Replace Function`.

I will end by giving a couple examples of how a less junior programmer might have coded this routine.

---

Consider:

```
s2.Activate

N = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim from(1 To N)
ReDim too(1 To N)
For i = 1 To N
    from(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
    too(i) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i
```

One of the first things you learn when you start learning VBA is “Do not activate worksheets or select cells”.  These are slow commands and even if you use `ScreenUpdating = False` there will be some screen rewriting.  More importantly, your code can become very confusing.  The following is better:

```
With s2

  N = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ReDim from(1 To N)
  ReDim too(1 To N)
  For i = 1 To N
   from(i) = .Cells(i, 1).Value
   too(i) = .Cells(i, 2).Value
  Next i

End With
```

Note 1: the periods before the three `Cells`.  `Cells` operates on the active worksheet.  `.Cells` operates on the worksheet specified in the `With` statement.

Note 2: I have not placed a period before `Rows.Count`.   `Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in the active worksheet.  `.Rows.Count` returns the number of rows in the specified worksheet.  The number of rows depends on the version of Excel and does not vary from worksheet to worksheet so most programmers do not bother with the period.

---

I would have made the two Worksheets parameters:

```
Sub xLator2(s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet)
```

This makes the subroutine much more flexible.  I would probably go further and make the parameters Ranges which would give even more flexibility.

---

I could continue but I believe that is enough to start with. Good luck and welcome to the joys of programming.

---

**Edit:  Tutorial and complete solution**

**Part 1 - One reason not use Activate**

Please study the following blocks of code which show why only the most junior VBA programmers use `Activate` without a very good reason.  I do not want you to get too uptight about saving a few seconds or milliseconds.  There are programmers who will spend half-an-hour to optimise a routine that is only run now and again.  Only if a routine is to be run hundreds of times a day can that time be justified. I want you to appreciate that `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` *can* save a lot of time so you use it automatically.  When `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is included, the difference between `Activate` and `With` is a lot less but enough to justify making `With` the default choice.

```
  For Count = 1 To 10000             ' This takes 148 seconds
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' This takes 11 seconds
  For Count = 1 To 10000
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' This takes .07 seconds
  For Count = 1 To 10000
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    End With
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' This takes 12 seconds
  For Count = 1 To 10000
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Cells(23, 1).Value = "A"
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Cells(23, 1).Value = "A"
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' This takes 1.16 seconds
  For Count = 1 To 10000
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
      .Cells(23, 1).Value = "A"
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
      .Cells(23, 1).Value = "A"
    End With
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' This takes 0.96 seconds
  Set Wsht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set Wsht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
  For Count = 1 To 10000
    With Wsht1
      .Cells(23, 1).Value = "A"
    End With
    With Wsht2
      .Cells(23, 1).Value = "A"
    End With
  Next
```

**Part 2 - Copying values from a worksheet to an array**

Macro `LoadFromTo1()` is based on the opening code of your macro which loads the From and Too tables. It is slightly different because my test data is slightly different.  It takes six-tenths of a seconds to load the From and Too table

```
Sub LoadFromTo1()

  ' Takes about .594 seconds for 50,000 rows * 2 columns

  Dim s1 As Worksheet
  Dim N As Long, i As Long
  Dim From(), too()

  Dim InxFromTo As Long
  Dim TimeStart As Single

  TimeStart = Timer

  Set s1 = Sheets("Test1") '   contains the data

  s1.Activate

  N = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
  ReDim From(1 To N - 1)
  ReDim too(1 To N - 1)
  For i = 2 To N
    From(i - 1) = Cells(i, 3).Value
    too(i - 1) = Cells(i, 4).Value
  Next i

  Debug.Print "M1: " & Timer - TimeStart

  For InxFromTo = 1 To 20
    Debug.Print Right("    " & InxFromTo, 5) & " " & From(InxFromTo) & " " & too(InxFromTo)
  Next
  For InxFromTo = UBound(From) - 20 To UBound(From)
    Debug.Print Right("    " & InxFromTo, 5) & " " & From(InxFromTo) & " " & too(InxFromTo)
  Next

End Sub
```

Macro `LoadFromTo2()` (not shown) used `With` instead of `Activate`.  With only only one `Activate` or `With` there was no noticiable change in performance.

Macro `LoadFromTo3()` uses a different technique for loading the tables. Insteading of importing the cell values one at a time, it imports then in a single statement: `CellValue = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(RowMax, 4)).Value`.  This statement will probably seems strange to you now.  However, if you study and practice the technique, it will become second nature.  I find `LoadFromTo3()` easier to code and understand than `LoadFromTo1()` and it is ten times as fast.  I have read that importing a range as a unit rather than cell by cell can be fifty times faster although I have never achieved that level of performance improvement.

```
Sub LoadFromTo3()

  ' Takes about .0625 seconds for 50,000 rows * 2 columns

  Const ColFrom As Long = 1
  Const ColTo As Long = 2

  Dim s1 As Worksheet
  Dim RowMax As Long, RowCrnt As Long

  Dim InxFromTo As Long
  Dim TimeStart As Single

  Dim CellValue As Variant

  TimeStart = Timer

  Set s1 = Sheets("Test1") '   contains the data

  With s1
    RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    CellValue = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(RowMax, 4)).Value

    Debug.Print "M3: " & Timer - TimeStart

  End With

  For InxFromTo = 1 To 20
    Debug.Print Right("    " & InxFromTo, 5) & " " & CellValue(InxFromTo, ColFrom) & _
                                               " " & CellValue(InxFromTo, ColTo)
  Next
  For InxFromTo = UBound(CellValue, 1) - 20 To UBound(CellValue, 1)
    Debug.Print Right("    " & InxFromTo, 5) & " " & CellValue(InxFromTo, ColFrom) & _
                                               " " & CellValue(InxFromTo, ColTo)
  Next

End Sub
```

**Part 3 - Analysis of original code**

First some definitions.  The *Target range* is the column of words to be translated.  The *Target table* is the the Target range loaded into memory.  The FromTo Range is the From and To columns.  The *FromTo table* is the the FromTo range loaded into memory.

This section has taken longer than I originally planned.  Initially I only intended to conduct a proper test of my code.  With the error in the code provided in an earlier answer and the implication there was another error, I was especially careful.  I coded a routine that generated test data of varying sizes.  I used that routine to generate the 50,000 row FromTo table I used for the timings in Part 2.  I made some minor changes to the translate routine you published and ran it against my test data to give the following durations:

```
FromTo  Target  Target  Duration  
  Rows    Rows    Cols   in secs
50,000      20       1       103
50,000  10,000       1       486
10,000   3,000       2        60
```

The key section of my modified code was:

```
With RngTgt
    For RowFromTo = 1 To UBound(FromToTable, 1)
      .Replace What:=FromToTable(RowFromTo, ColFrom), _
               Replacement:="__" + Str(RowFromTo), _
               LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next
    For RowFromTo = 1 To UBound(FromToTable, 1)
      .Replace What:="__" + Str(RowFromTo), _
               Replacement:=FromToTable(RowFromTo, ColTo), _
               LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next
  End With
```

I use a range so the Target range can be in any worksheet and be multi-column.  I did not see the point of having such a large prefix and suffix which must result in a time penalty so I reduced to a prefix of two underscores.  I include the `LookAt:=xlWhole` correction.  I use a ToFrom table loaded from range.  I have replaced `i` by the meaningful name `RowFromTo` to make the code more understandable.

There are no comments saying what this code does and why it does it this way.  It is essential to include adequate comments in a macro.  Will you remember what this macro does in six or twelve months?  What if a colleague needs to amend it?

In your first FromTo table, "for" translates to "on" and "on" translates" to "upon".   Without the two pass solution. "for" might be translated to "upon".  This is my guess and it seems reasonable but there should have been a comment so I did not need to guess.  A new programmer taking responsibility for this macro might be unable to guess and might "improve" the code by removing the "unnecessary" second pass.

The code behind the Replace method will be as efficient as its authors can manage but it will still have to examine every cell in the range.  I have improved the situation by searching a specified range rather than the whole worksheet.  However, it still has to search that range twice for every row in the FromTo table.

Studying this code I saw an immediate improvement.  The first pass replaces the words in the Target table with "__1", "__2", "__n" and so on where 1, 2 and n are indices into the FromTo table.  The second pass searches for "__1", "__2" and "__n".  A better technique is to extract the 1, 2 and n and use them to access the correct entry in the FromTo table.  With this better technique the duration were:

```
                           First    Second
FromTo  Target  Target  duration  duration
  Rows    Rows    Cols   in secs   in secs
50,000      20       1       103        52
50,000  10,000       1       486       257
10,000   3,000       2        60        32
```

That is, I halved the duration by changing the code to:

```
  With RngTgt
    For RowFromTo = 1 To UBound(ToFromTable, 1)
      .Replace What:=ToFromTable(RowFromTo, ColFrom), _
               Replacement:="__" + Str(RowFromTo), _
               LookAt:=xlWhole
    Next
  End With

  For Each Cell In RngTgt
    Test = Mid(Cell.Value, 3)
    If IsNumeric(Test) Then
      Cell.Value = ToFromTable(Val(Test), ColTo)
    End If
  Next
```

However, I believed the basic approach to be wrong.  If there are FT entries in the FromTo range and T entries in the Target range then:

- With approach 1 there are 2 * FT replaces that require the searching of T cells.
- With approach 2 there are FT replaces that require the searching of T cells and then T replaces.

Since the same word may repeat within the Target range, the search of the Target range must examine every cell.  But what if we searched the From column of the FromTo rangw for each entry in the Target range?  Unless there are a large number of words in the Target range that are missing from the FromTo range, an average FT / 2 entries will be examined before a match is found.  Also there is no need for a second pass.  We would expect a third approach based on this logical, to half the approach 2 durations.

I recoded the main part of my routine and repeated the tests

```
                           First    Second      Third
FromTo  Target  Target  duration  duration   duration
  Rows    Rows    Cols   in secs   in secs    in secs
50,000      20       1       103        52        .13
50,000  10,000       1       486       257      61.51 
10,000   3,000       2        60        32       7.54
```

This as a much bigger reduction in duration than I was expecting.  I have some guesses as to the reason but I have not investigated further.  I believe the final durations are acceptable.  I have one further idea but I do not think it is worth the time to imvestigate.

The major lesson of the above is: think about your implementation startegy before implementing it.  To me technique 3 is obviously superior to techniques 1 and 2 and I would have started with that technique.  Some time spent on initial design can repay itself hansomely.

**Part 4 - Final solution**

You posted two workbooks each with the Target range in Sheet1 and the FromTo range in Sheet2.  I created one workbook with the data from the second workbook copied to Sheet3 and Sheet3.

I amended your macro to call my macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub xLator2()

  Dim RngTgt As Range
  Dim RngFromTo As Range
  Dim RowMax As Long
  Dim TimeStart  As Single

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngTgt = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(RowMax, "A"))
  End With

  With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngFromTo = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(RowMax, "B"))
  End With

  TimeStart = Timer
  Call Translate3(RngTgt, RngFromTo)
  Debug.Print "Sheet1 technique 3 duration: " & Timer - TimeStart

  With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngTgt = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(RowMax, "A"))
  End With

  With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngFromTo = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(RowMax, "B"))
  End With

  TimeStart = Timer
  Call Translate3(RngTgt, RngFromTo)
  Debug.Print "Sheet3 technique 3 duration: " & Timer - TimeStart

End Sub
```

My macro for technique 3 takes two ranges as its parameters so there can be multiple Target and FromTo ranges which can be placed where ever convenient:

```
Sub Translate3(ByVal RngTgt As Range, ByVal RngFromTo As Range)

  ' RngTgt     A rectangle containing words to be translated
  ' RngFromTo  Two columns with the left column containing the original values
  '            for words and the right column containing the values to replace
  '            the original values.

  ' Constants numbering the From and To columns within RngFromTo.  This makes the
  ' code easier to understand than if 1 and 2 had been used.
  Const ColFrom As Long = 1
  Const ColTo As Long = 2

  Dim ColTgtCrnt As Long
  Dim Test As String
  Dim RngFindStart As Range
  Dim RngFrom As Range
  Dim RngTemp As Range
  Dim RowFromTo As Long
  Dim RowTgtCrnt As Long
  Dim TgtTable As Variant

  ' Check FromTo range has two columns
  If RngFromTo.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
    Call MsgBox("ToFrom table must have two columns", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Load Target range to array
  TgtTable = RngTgt.Value

  ' Set RngFrom to the From column of RngFromTo
  Set RngFrom = RngFromTo.Columns(ColFrom)
  ' Set RngFindStart to first cell of RngFrom
  Set RngFindStart = RngFrom.Rows(1)

  ' Loop for every entry in Target table
  For RowTgtCrnt = 1 To UBound(TgtTable, 1)
    For ColTgtCrnt = 1 To UBound(TgtTable, 2)
      Set RngTemp = RngFrom.Find(What:=TgtTable(RowTgtCrnt, ColTgtCrnt), _
                                 After:=RngFindStart, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If Not RngTemp Is Nothing Then
        ' This target cell is to be translated
        ' Replace value in Target table with value for To column of FromTo table
        TgtTable(RowTgtCrnt, ColTgtCrnt) = RngTemp.Offset(0, ColTo - ColFrom).Value
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' Upload updated array back to Target range
  RngTgt.Value = TgtTable

End Sub
```

There is a lot to study here.  Take it slowly and look up any statement you do not understand.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you understand on your own, the faster you will develop.

Comment: Your calls of the `Replace method` use the `What` and `Replacement` parameters.  What other parameter does the `Replace method` have that will stop it replacing part of a cell?

Comment: I would be very very very very and very thankful to you if you can provide me entire code which I can copy paste and run directly.

Comment: Adding `, LookAt:=xlWhole` to the end of the two rows starting `Cells.Replace` will fix the bug.  I will think about rewriting the existing code.  Where did you find this code?

Comment: I have got it from; http://superuser.com/questions/777648/find-and-replace-multiple-words-in-a-column-in-excel-2007

Comment: But please don't get confused with that question since this is modified one.

Comment: I would be really very thankful to you if u can provide whole code, I have tried your suggestion , LookAt:=xlWhole but it is not working.

Comment: What goes wrong when you try adding `, LookAt:=xlWhole`? I could not see any errors in the transalations when I did that.

Comment: Just spotted an error in the comment I posted 2.5 hours ago. I should perhaps add that there is no point my providing a complete routine if you are aware of an error in the original code that I have overlooked.

Comment: ' -------------- Modification starts here --------------------------
' Replace from from(i) to __MYREPLACEMENTi__  (where i is the counter)
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__"
Next i
' Replace from __MYREPLACEMENTi__ to too(i)  (where i is the counter)
For i = LBound(from) To UBound(from)
    Cells.Replace What:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__", Replacement:=too(i)
Next i
' -------------- Modification ends here --------------------------, LookAt:=xlWhole
End Sub]

Comment: Why haven't you placed `, LookAt:=xlWhole` at the end of the two rows starting `Cells.Replace` as I said?  So `Cells.Replace What:=from(i), Replacement:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__", LookAt:=xlWhole` and `Cells.Replace What:="__MYREPLACEMENT" + Str(i) + "__", Replacement:=too(i), LookAt:=xlWhole`

Comment: @user3811050  I have added a new solution which is substantially faster than your code together with a tutorial explaining how I developed the new solution.